# How can I add letter in front of grid/map without ruining loop and replace values in the map afterwards?

Tags: python, list, loops, grid

I have an assignment to program a simple tower defense game in python through printing.
I managed to print the map/grid. But I'm not sure if I'm using the correct method because I'll need to replace the spaces in the map later. I was given a nested list with `None` variables. I'm not sure if I need to use it, and also there should be a letter in front of every row with A,B,C,D,E. How am I supposed to add this into my code, 'cause it'll probably mess up the loop?

What I'm supposed to get:

[image: figure]

This is my current code without using the `None` variable

```
field = [ [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None] ]

num_rows=len(field)
num_columns=len(field[0])
    
for column in range(num_columns): 
    print('+----',end='')
print('+')

for row in range(num_rows):
    for column in field[row]:
        print("|    ",end='')
    print('|')
    for column in field[row]:
        print("|    ",end='')
    print('|')
    for column in range(num_columns):
        print('+----', end = '')
    print('+')
```

which prints this:

[image: figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
field = [ [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
        [None, None, None, None, None, None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15")],
        [None, ("ZOMBI", "15/15"), None, None, None, None, None] ]

num_rows=len(field)
num_columns=len(field[0])

row_indexes="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
padding = " " * 5 # 5 spaces

### print column index
print(" " * 2, end="") # padding
for column in range(1, num_columns+1):
    print(f"  {column}   ", end="")
print()

print(" ", end="")
for column in range(num_columns): 
    print('+-----',end='')
print('+')

for row in range(num_rows):
    print(f"{row_indexes[row]}", end="") # print row index
    for column in range(num_columns):
        element = field[row][column]
        if element is None:
            print("|" + padding, end='')
        else:
            print("|" + element[0], end='')
    print('|')

    print(' ', end="")
    for column in range(num_columns):
        element = field[row][column]
        if element is None:
            print("|" + padding, end='')
        else:
            print("|" + element[1], end='')
    print('|')

    print(" ", end="") # padding
    for column in range(num_columns):
        print('+-----', end = '')
    print('+')
```

**Output:**

```
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7   
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
A|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
B|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
C|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
D|     |     |     |     |     |     |ZOMBI|
 |     |     |     |     |     |     |15/15|
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
E|     |ZOMBI|     |     |     |     |     |
 |     |15/15|     |     |     |     |     |
 +-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```